# Display only 1 comment and then option to show more

Tags: comments

I want to display only 1 comment and then have an option to "show more" to show the rest of the comments.

The story behind this is that I've on the homepage a feed with cards for blog posts and I added the comments section to this post card, so when the post has many comments they are all shown and it makes the post card look bad and the homepage too long.

I tried lazy load comments plugin but it just implement the lazy loading of the comments either on click or on scroll but still, when the comments are loaded they are shown all.

Thanks
Eslam